# Safari/Chrome Developer Tools debug CSS overrides

Tags: safari, google-chrome-devtools

Safari/Chrome Developer Tools indicate that a CSS rule is overridden by something else by striking it through, as shown in the image.

[image: Striked-through CSS rule]

Sometimes I find myself in a situation where I can not figure out from the CSS files what causes this rule to be ignored. But surely Safari itself must know as it strikes it through.

Is there a way to know what overrides such a rule?

Comment: Dev tools shows the file source across from the selector.

Comment: You might benefit from reading through help documentation of chrome's Dev tools rather than expecting a quick guide from here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the one which isn't striked out, higher up on the list.

Alternatively, view the *computed styles*. They will be the definitive applied styles.

Comment: Thank you, I had missed that Safari orders the blocks by the importance, not CSS order. My case was that longer selector (table.class td) got higher than shorter although more specific selector (.class) that matches single td.

Comment: Definitely use the _Computed Styles_ pane for this. You'll be able to see exactly the cascade that led to the final computed result.

Answer (score 3):

When you inspect an element, you can show the 'box'. Just bottom of that, you have a 'filter' which should show you every properties being applied to your element.

If you click on a property, it will give you the file and the line number.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Developer Tools will list all rules for an element. Just read through all the CSS rules that apply, and check for a non-struck-through one with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Elements >> Computed and you'll get the stylesheet that defines the rule you're looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **Computed** tab of Chrome Developer tools. Find wanted property and expand details.

[image: Screenshot]