# Class attributes not applied to a button

Tags: css, html, button

I have a button and I want to make it be very big:

```
<button type="submit" class="button">Compra</button>
```

I'm correctly (I already have feedback) linking a CSS file that contains this class:

```
.title
{
    font-size:75px;
    text-align:center;
    color:blue;
    font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,Serif;
}

.subtitle
{
    font-size:50px;
    font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,Serif;
}

.text
{
    font-size:25px;
    font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,Serif;
}

.table
{
    font-size:25px;
    font-family:"Times New Roman",Georgia,Serif;
    border: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    border-spacing: 20px 10px;
}

.button
{
    width:280px;
    height:280px;
}
```

But the button isn't affected by the button class size. If I do it this way:

```
<body>
    <form action="Purchase.xhtml" method="post">
        <button type="submit" class="button">Compra</button>
        ... (other code)
```

It works, but I need to use a CSS file because I have many buttons, and it may happen that I want to change them all, so in this case I would just change the CSS file.

Does someone know why the button class width/height property doesn't influence the button size?

Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/K2LLB/1

**Edit**

It works on firefox but not on chrome.

Comment: seems to work just fine => http://jsfiddle.net/K2GVz/

Comment: What other styles do you have? Possibly something reseting the button, or .button, element?  A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) containing your full example would be helpful.

Comment: That's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K2LLB/

Comment: It's working in your demo.

Comment: And that's the strange part, I'm using netbeans and the html is contained in a jsp file, there's a very small button.

Comment: Are you familiar with Firebug? If not, now's the time to become so.

Comment: It's all the above (after the edit).

Answer (score 0):

Some other style declarations in your page have precedence over .button, either by specificity or load order. We'd need to see more code or your demo page to say more.

Comment: I edited the answer. I put this button just after the body tag opens, I don't think there isn't another style applied.

Comment: This post will be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876936/safari-chrome-developer-tools-debug-css-overrides (Debugging CSS overrides)